# Cannot read integer values saved into binary file with Java

Tags: python, java

I implemented a procedure for saving 32bit signed integer values, retrieved from PostgreSQL, into a binary file.

I used ByteArrayOutputStream and DataOutputStream

```
//..


ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(baos);

//this cycle over my retrieved recordset
while (tdb.next()) {

   out.writeInt((tdb.getInteger(1)));  //getInteger method extract integer value from recordset

}

//convert into byte array
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

//create file for output
File fileout = new File("./myfilebin.bin");
//write data
Files.write(fileout.toPath(), bytes);

//...
```

My input data sample contains these values:

> 0, 0, 42812, 42822, 41483, 0, 0, ...

When I try to read my binary file, I will get these:

> 0, 0, 1017577472, 1185349632, 195166208, 0, 0, ...

For reading file I wrote a simple python script:

```
import struct

with open("./myfilebin.bin", "rb") as f:

     for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4), ''):
        integer_value = struct.unpack('i', chunk)[0]
        print(integer_value)
```

Any idea?

Comment: How do you know those are the actual input numbers? Making 5398449 out of 48 does not appear possible here. The python code reads LE, the javacode writes BE, so that's a problem, but you'd get 805306368, not 5398449.

Comment: Why the `ByteArrayOutputStream`? Just wrap the `DataOutputStream` around the `FileOutputStrream` and write directly to the file. If you need it quicker, put a `BufferedOutputStream` in between them.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I make it 11624274. OP needs to provide a hex dump of the file.

Comment: yes, the problem was the different behaviour between javacode and python code for endian management

Comment: @rzwitserloot :I wrote a wrong sample. Sorry for that

Comment: So what is the *correct* sample? You can't expect a solution if you don't provide all the relevant data.

Comment: @user207421 : I apologize for that, I just put the right sample in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your numbers are Big-Endian (BE) and you try to decode as Little-Endian (LE).

Try: `struct.unpack('>i', chunk)` to force reading as BE.

See also the [docs for struct module on alignment and endianess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).

FYI, `DataOutputStream` always writes in BE as stated in the [official javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt(int)).

Comment: if I change the decode option, output changes but still wrong numbers

Comment: @N3tMaster, can you share a sample of the binary file. For example, for first 32 bytes: `head -c 32 file.bin | xxd`.

Comment: @user207421, both links are correct; the 1st link states that bytes are written "high byte first" or in other words big-endian.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was the different behaviour in bit reading order between python, that uses LE, and java.

I need to create a binary file that follows ISOBUS standards and I have to write it using LE.

So I change my code in this way:

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("myfileout.bin");

            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(fout);


            while (tdb.next()) {
                //convert byte endian behaviour for ISOBUS software compatibility
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
                bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                bb.putInt(tdb.getInteger(1));
                //invert significant byte
                bb.flip();

                out.write(bb.array());
            }

            fout.close();
            out.close();
```

Comment: you code is correct, but your comment on `flip` is wrong: [`flip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip()) does not change endianess, just sets the position to 0 so that you can read what you have previously written on the buffer

Comment: you are right, but te final result is a switched bytes (BE with LE) when data is written out